# Unable to run OpenCV code from beaglebone

Tags: c++, opencv, beagleboneblack

I am trying to run a program using OpenCV in beaglebone black as described at the end of the link https://solarianprogrammer.com/2014/04/21/opencv-beaglebone-black-ubuntu/

I had some compilation issues which I resolved using

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` test_2.cpp -o test_2
```

It successfully compiles, but when I try to run using

```
./test_2
```

I get the error:

> CMEM Error: init: Failed to open /dev/cmem: 'No such file or
>   directory'
>
> The cmemk kernel module does not appear to be installed.
>
> Commands such as the following run as root would install cmemk and
>   allow OpenCL to proceed properly.
>
> For available CMEM DDR block size: ~512MB: modprobe cmemk
>   phys_start=0xa0000000 phys_end=0xc0000000 pools=1x536870912
>   allowOverlap=1

I am not sure why I am getting this, and I've been unable to resolve it for a few days already. Please guide me into right direction.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

So, I had the same problem (running from the latest Debian release on the beaglebone site - 8.5).

I found this link [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/beagleboard@googlegroups.com/msg42027.html) - which suggested I do these things:

```
For older images do this:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get remove dkms --purge  #get rid of dkms/etc..

cd /opt/scripts/tools/
git pull
sudo ./update_kernel.sh
sudo reboot

cd /usr/share/ti/examples/opencl/float_compute/
sudo make
sudo modprobe cmemk
sudo ./float_compute
```

Now, the update_kernel.sh didn't actually fully work (grep breaks on the last update-initramfs), so I tried installing `initramfs-tools`, but it still didn't work... so then I just commented it out. After rebooting, I tried to find the opencvl/float_compute folder... but that didn't exist so I just ran my code and hoped for the best and it actually worked.

So, my suggestion is to do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get remove dkms --purge  #get rid of dkms/etc..

cd /opt/scripts/tools/
git pull
sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools
```

Then edit update_kernel by commenting out the `update-initramfs -uk ${latest_kernel}` line in the `third_party_final()` method (just add as # in front of the line). Then do:

```
sudo ./update_kernel.sh
sudo reboot
```

Installing the initramfs-tools might not be necessary, but I'm not sure. I have a feeling the actual solution is just the `remove dkms` or the update of the kernel, but again, not sure. All I can say it doing all of that worked for me.